# how to integrate voice chat using php?

Tags: php, livechat

How to integrate a voice chat using php?

i am open to skype or use any plugins which can be instructed by php, a pre built script would also work!

Comment: are you looking to integrate voice chat to one of your own apps in php? What are you attempting to do? I mean what's the requirement?

Comment: i want to make a paid online course website where a user can pay and then talk to the expert over voice.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work, as PHP is server-side and any voice-chat software is client-side.

Comment: so any client side recommendations ? and doesn't skype offers a linux based library which can be instructed by php?